# Interactive shell using standard input

Tags: pipe, sh, posix

I'd like to launch a shellscript which has interactive parts inside via pipe.

For example,

```
cat hoge.sh | sh
```

and hoge.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
read yn
echo "yn is $yn"
```

In this case, `sh hoge.sh` works but `cat hoge.sh | sh` not.

Which option should I put ? or is it impossible?
hopefully, I make a script which follows POSIX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Method 1: Get user input via stderr

The problem is stdin for the shell is the `cat` process and, apparently, you would like the question the user.  One way to do that is:

```
$ cat hoge.sh
#!/bin/sh
read yn <&2
echo "yn is $yn"
```

This tells `read` to get its stdin from the stderr, not the `cat` process.  Since stderr has not been redirected, it is still the terminal

In operation, it looks like this:

```
$ cat hoge.sh | sh
y
yn is y
```

#### Method 2: Get user input directly from the terminal

```
$ cat hoge.sh
#!/bin/sh
read yn </dev/tty
echo "yn is $yn"
```

When done this way, the `read` command will get its input from the terminal and any attempt at I/O redirection will be ignored.  This can be an advantage or disadvantage depending on your requirements.

Comment: Both worked in a simple case. I will consider my environment. Thank you very much.

Comment: A dedicated file descriptor would be preferable to abusing standard error like this. `read yn <&3`, then run the script with something like `cat input | hoge.sh 3< /dev/tty`. (Or whatever other file user confirmation should come from.)